# GDK Show the Map in Google Glass

Tags: google-glass

I want to create a sample glass application using the Google Glass Development Kit.
In my activity I want to show the Google map.
How can I show the map in activity using Google Glass Development Kit?

Comment: See this (duplicate) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333616/how-to-display-static-map-on-card-using-gdk